# Spring Security: how to add add Failure handler

Tags: java, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security, siteminder

I have a question about spring security.

Now I use a siple `siteMinderFilter` to restrict access to several pages:

```
    RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter siteMinderFilter = new RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter (ignored);
    siteMinderFilter.setPrincipalRequestHeader("SM_USER");
    siteMinderFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
```

In the case when SM_USER is wrong I want my SmUserFailureHandler to be used:

```
@Component
public class SmUserFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SmUserFailureHandler.class);

@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) 
                                                                                                throws IOException, ServletException {
      super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);

      log.debug("got AuthenticationException");
      if(exception.getClass().isAssignableFrom(PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException.class)) {
      log.debug("got PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException");

     } 
   }
}
```

and then in spring confguration class

```
@Bean
public SmUserFailureHandler smUserFailureHandler(){
    return new SmUserFailureHandler();
}
```

But now I cannot understand how can I include this in my authenticationProvider. The single position to use such a FailureHandler that I found is a login form

```
http.formLogin().loginPage("/my/login/page/").failureHandler(smUserFailureHandler());
```

but I want it to be applied for **all** the resources which require SM_USER.

How can I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

You are working with **Authentication**FailureHandler ... authentication can be successfull or not - you do not care about the resources. If authentication is successfull - you have the logged in user - then there is authorization, the proccess that checks if user have rights for requested resource. You need to generate/process AccessDenied situation.

The easier way is to override the logic in processing AccessDeniedException (but this is generated for **every** access denied)

```
<bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="authenticationEntryPoint" />
    <property name="accessDeniedHandler" ref="accessDeniedHandler" />
</bean>

<bean id="accessDeniedHandler" class="org.springframework.security.ui.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl">
    <property name="errorPage" value="/noaccess.jsp" />
</bean>
```

source: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/62027-redirect-on-authorization-failure?p=463489#post463489

If you want to generate special message for given resource then you will have to change something else. Maybe it needs just an AccessDecisionVoter, but I haven't used that.